# Drag an Image From Div and Place in Canvas

Tags: php, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I needed a query or example on how to drag and Image from a div and place it into a canvas. 
I am using Jquery and KineticJs get some success in it.

My aim is to drag an image and can perform various functionaly in canvas similar to http://polyvore.com/cgi/app

Thank You.

Comment: And your question is? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that JQuery and KineticJS are that interchangeable that you could do such a thing easily. Essentially you would need a function that stores data about the JQuery image, a function which detects when the canvas has been entered (mouseover) and starts tracking movement, and finally a function which copies information from the JQuery image div and 'converts' it to something KineticJS would recognize.

```
 function convert(imageDiv){
     var config = $('#divId').getInfo();  //another function you'd need to create to grab configuration of stored image.
     var kineticImage = new Kinetic.Image(config);
 }
```